# Explicitly call Model object in Rails Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a `module`:

```
module Api         # in dir app/controllers/api/status/
  module Status
    def index
      render json: Status.all # this Status is referring to the Status model object
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `Status` in `index` it refers to the `module Status`, is there a way to explicitly refer to the `model Status` object?

Note: the Status module was created to help organize my code, and I don't want to rename it to something like `Statuses`.

Comment: try `::Status.all` to use the default ruby namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
::Status.all
```

The :: is a unary operator that allows: constants, instance methods and class methods defined within a class or module, to be accessed from anywhere outside the class or module. http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/ruby-double-colon.html